# Is there a name for this kind of matrix decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, positive-definite

A square matrix $\mathbf{A}$ (of size $a\times a$) is not full rank and I want to decompose it as $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^\top$ where $\mathbf{B}$ is an $a\times(a-1)$ matrix of the $a-1$ eigenvectors of unit length corresponding to the nonzero eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$.

For example, $\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & -1/2\\ -1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{B}=(\sqrt{2}/2,-\sqrt{2}/2)^\top$ when $a=2$.

*Question*: Is there a name for this kind of matrix decomposition?

Comment: Please do not use $a$. Come on.

Comment: This is kind of the Cholesky decomposition, but $\bf A$ needs to be symmetric and positive semidefinite